# Tags related to climate, with at least one synonym proposal

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have [rainfall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainfall) x15 and [precipitation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precipitation) x7.

We also have [climate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) and [solar-radiation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-radiation).

I don't currently see any others that would fall under the category of climate (such as wind), but feel free to edit if you find more.

Should some or all of these tags be combined via synonym?

Comment: There seems to be no diverging views and whuber has already implemented your proposed synonym so I think this one has been completed.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'd agree. The rainfall/precipitation was the main thing I was bringing up, but I figured we could consider whether all climate variables should be lumped under one tag. Neither I or apparently anyone else thinks so, so unless such an answer/opinion should show up in the future I'd consider it done.

Answer (score 2):

[rainfall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainfall) should be made synonym to [precipitation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precipitation). While rainfall is more commonly used in terms of questions, precipitation is the proper word that would encompass both rain and snow (along with whatever other forms you want to throw in there) and I see little use in differentiating them at the tag level.

Both are a subset of [climate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) data, as is [solar-radiation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-radiation), but I think individual climate variables are specific enough to justify their own tags. I'm mildly surprised there isn't a temperature or wind tag, given there are several specific questions about those variables.

Comment: +1 Both are good suggestions. The first is a no-brainer so I have taken care of it.  However, I made [tag:precipitation] the main tag because it has a slightly broader meaning than "rainfall," despite being used less frequently.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that was my thought as well.